# how do you store char and int in same variable?

Tags: c++

i know that int and char cant be specified by different data types and char basically represents the ASCII values. what confuses me is storing them in the SAME data type which can be used later on. For example, if i were to input int and char both type of data from the user in variable x, how would i define the variable? like with what type of it?
lets say you were to input integers from the user and when the user enters a symbol('='), the program ends.

```
void main()
{
    int count, flag = 0;
    int i = 0;

    int x = 0;
    const int ASCII_VALUE_OF_EQ = '='

    x = ASCII_VALUE_OF_EQ;
    for (i = 0; i <=10; i++){
        cout << "Enter the number = ";
        cin >> x;


        if (x == ASCII_VALUE_OF_EQ)
            break;
    }
    //to find if the number before '=' was prime
    int m = 2; int c = 0;  

    while (m < x)
    {
        if (x%m == 0){
            c++;
            break;
        }

        m++;
    }
    if (c == 0){
        cout << x << " is a Prime number"<<endl<<"here are all the prime numbers         that come before '='" << endl;

        for (int a = 2; a <= x; a++)
        {
            int c = 0;
            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++)
            {
                if (a%b == 0)

                c++;

            }
            if (c == 2){
                cout << a << endl;
                continue;
            }

        }


    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: An `int` is big enough to store all values of a `char`, so this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: sometimes its just easier to do some arithmetical operation on ascii character than with letter itself. Keep in mind that c++ is lower level than Java or C#. Machine even when you say char it sees it as ascii number.

Comment: `const int ASCII_VALUE_OF_EQ = '=';` may tell you something if you think about it for awhile. And your extracting *`int`* from your stream. If you want to test `char` literals, you need a different extraction mechanism.

Comment: yeah, it tells me that i have wasted about an hour already.

Comment: @WhozCraig, even then the loop is not broken, since the value in x is still an int type. it does not read the char '=' and hence doesn't terminate the if(condition).

Comment: @GulrukhKhan so the ultimate intent is to read strings as `int` unless someone enters a solo `=` ? is the ultimately the end-goal here?

Comment: @WhozCraig the intent is to read **int** unless someone enters a solo **=**, this part of the code is holding me back.

Comment: So, the real question is, how do i use the `cin >>` type structure when i don't know what type the right side will be yet? I am thinking you will need to send it to a string, check types, then make a `stringstream` out of the string for final extraction.

Comment: ^ i tried making a stringstream too but im new to programming so its really eating me up. find me a way to it?

Comment: A `char` is a number.  It just so happens that we have a convention (actually several different ones) that assign numeric values to specific characters, so that (assuming ASCII) we know that the number 75 means the letter "K".  But if we assume EBCDIC, the same 75 value means "." (period).  The computer doesn't know the difference, it's only when the numeric value is sent to your display screen that the number is translated to pixels that show "K" (or ".").

Comment: As I see WhozCraig posted an answer that is basically a possible implementation I was talking about. You have to perform a very simple task and your code is a bit ugly. Cut out some parts of the code into separate functions, for example IsPrime(x) would be a nice unit of work to put into its separate function.

Comment: This isn't going to turn into an online-debugging session. You asked a specific question. The mechanism I posted addressed that specific question and was based on answers to questions above about *exactly* what your needs were. The updated code chose to adopt exactly *none* of the aforementioned suggestion and is no better off than when first posted, so I'm dropping my answer. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: ^well that escalated quickly anyways, thankyou. sooner or later i will find a way! :D